# Visual studio how to open file and not diff window in team explorer changes git

Tags: git, visual-studio

Before commit my file on git, I want edit my file, but when I click on the file in the changes window in team explorer, it open the diff of previous file and current file, but how to open juste the current file, for edit it. Because in large solution find file is not easy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It really was not easy to find in VS 2017:

- Go to the Team explorer window
- Changes tab
- Click on '...' button near Changes accordion
- select Open file as default action

[image: Git open file as default]

Comment: Still working in VS 2022 17.8. After applying this change, it is still possible to still open the diff with SHIFT + DoubleClick.

Answer (score 17):

I've found way to: press SHIFT + double-click. This provided me with alternative behaviour of opening files in VS 2019 Community Edition

Comment: Oh wow thanks. One little anoying thing is that you first have to close the diff window and then SHIFT + double-click will work. I can't understand when there is no button or something like in WebStorm...

Answer (score 3):

In VS2019 Enterprise I had 2 to do what **s_tranquil** said:

1. Click on '...' to open file as a default option
2. Plus what **Van-ng** said, but the opposite, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>double-click</kbd> to open the diff window.